# Call Django celery task by name

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to call a celery task (in tasks.py) from models.py, the only problem is, tasks.py imports models.py, so I can't import tasks.py from models.py.

Is there some way to call a celery task simply using its name, without having to import it? A similar thing is implemented for ForeignKey fields for the same reason (preventing circular imports).

Comment: Did you try `celery.execute.send_task('mod.task_func', [arg1, arg2], {kwarg: kwvalue})`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You can use:

```
from celery.execute import send_task    

send_task('my_task', [], kwargs)
```

Be sure that you task function has a name:

```
from celery import task

@task(name='my_task')
def my_task():
     ...
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

In Celery 3+:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()
app.send_task('my_task', [], kwargs)
```