# How to run tasks of Django Periodic Task Object [django-celery-beat]

Tags: django, django-models, celery, django-celery, celery-task

Django Celery Beat has an option in the admin panel where you can run tasks directly by selecting each individual `PeriodicTask` model object.

https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat

[image]

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask

get_task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(id=1)
```

- different objects have different tasks registered to them.
  How to execute the celery task by taking the values from the `PeriodicTask` model object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Django celery task by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239154/call-django-celery-task-by-name)

Answer (score 1):

```
from celery.execute import send_task   
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask
import json

get_task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(id=1)
get_task_registed_taskname = get_task.task
get_task_kwargs = json.loads(get_task.kwargs)

send_task(get_task_registed_taskname,[],get_task_kwargs)
```